# Problems linking to a library with gcc

Tags: gcc, linker, sfml

I installed [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/) from scratch today so I could work on a game. I downloaded the source, ran `sudo make install`, tried compiling one of my old projects, and I couldn't get it to link properly. So I tried running a simpler project: one of the samples in the tutorials. I tried to compile [this one](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/1.6/window-opengl.php) specifically, but I get these errors:

```
g++ -o atest test.cpp -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system /tmp/ccaa86fR.o: In function `main':
test.cpp:(.text+0x1d2): undefined reference to `gluPerspective'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

Trying an [even simpler project](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/1.6/start-linux.php), the one in the initial tutorial, I don't run into problems compiling. However, when I try to run it, I get this error:

```
./atest: error while loading shared libraries: libsfml-graphics.so.1.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I checked, and the files did install to /usr/local/lib/ which is where they're supposed to go as far as I know. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-lGLU` should fix the first error and for the second one make sure  `/usr/local/lib/` is in your ldconfig search path (`/etc/ld.so.conf` and `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/*` under Ubuntu) and that you ran ldconfig: `sudo ldconfig -v` then try running again.

see also `man ldconfig`